# Dunnett post-hoc test for a glmmTMB model with a gamma distribution

Tags: r, posthoc, glmmtmb, dunn.test

I built a glmmTMB model using a gamma distribution as my data look like a poisson distribution but with continuous variable.
My model looks like this:

```r
RB.ng.CO2_C.gsol.h ~ treatment * tree.specie + (1|bloc)
```

The `treatment` factor has 8 levels and the `tree.specie` factor has 6  levels.

I want to perform a Dunnett post-hoc test with this model to extract the significant difference between my results.

I have tried to do it using the `emmeans` package, but I got an error saying that glmmTMB cannot be handled.

```r
emm <- emmeans(m1, ~ treatment * tree.specie, data = RBA2022)
```

> Error in (function (object, at, cov.reduce = mean, cov.keep = get_emm_option("cov.keep"),  :  Can't handle an object of class  “glmmTMB”
> Use help("models", package = "emmeans") for information on supported models.

Do you have any idea of how to do that post-hoc test?

Comment: Can you please post your `sessionInfo()`?  Something like this works for me with the latest `glmmTMB`/`emmeans`.  Furthermore, if all you need is a Gamma response (and not zero-inflation or dispersion models or other stuff) then you should also be able to fit that model with `glmer`.